# Change Colour of Twitter-Bootstrap UI

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developing a website for a school task. I am quite new to HTML and CSS, so I don't know much about how I would do this.

I would like to change the default colour of the twitter-bootstrap UI on my `div class="well"` that located on the center of the page to `#BA935A`.

My website can be found [here](http://hiimstring3.hpage.com/). So I just need an idea of how I could do it.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, it wasn't done very well originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your source code, find following Snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
        background-color:#20437D;
    }
</style>
```

Change the `#20437D` to `#BA935A`.

You would get what you want.

Comment: Okay, this isn't what I was really getting at, I'll be a bit more specific. I do know how to change my background colour. My website has a background and in the center, a Twitter-Bootstrap UI. I am content with my background's colour, however, I want to change the colour of the UI in the center.

Comment: What UI? Can you tell more specific?

Comment: It falls under `<div class="well">`. When you go to the website, it is the grey box in the center. It has tabs at the top that allow you navigate through the page content. I want to change this grey colour to hex colour I specified in the question.

Comment: Ok, this might be useful. Open `bootstrap.css`, go to line 3067, change `background-color: #f5f5f5;` to `background-color: #BA935A;`. Or if you don't like the original `bootstrap.css` file to be modified. You can add a new `.css` file, with content `.well{background-color: #BA935A;}`, append this new css file into your html

Comment: Editing Bootstrap style I think it's not a wise move, since we can using bootstrap as a Gem.

Comment: True, as i said, if you intend to prevent editing bootstrap style. You can add an extra `.css` file to your html, that would work perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I've done this and it's worked, quite well, so thanks for that. I am however having a slight problem. While the background it changed, the tab selection area is still white. Do you know where in the code I can edit this?

Comment: The original place is line 4027 in `bootstrap.css`, i think in your newly added `.css` file, add following snippet to the end would work: `.well > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.well > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover {background-color: #BA935A;}`

Comment: Is the section you're refering to this `.input-group-addon:first-child` or is it a different section. If so what is it called?

Comment: No, the snippet is nothing to do with `.input-group-addon:first-child`. You can just append them to the end of your newly added `.css` file. Just like you did as the previous step for changing content background color.

Comment: Ah, well what actually did was go into the css file and edit there, but are you saying to make a new one and add this into it? or are you saying add it to the existing bootstrap.css file?

Comment: I am saying that better to have a new `.css` file without editing the existing `bootstrap.css`. You would see the right view as expectation if you fill this new `.css` file with following snippet: `.well > .nav-tabs > .active > a, .well > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover {background-color: #BA935A;}`.

Comment: I've made a css file with what you've said, and I've linked the file under the original bootstrap.css link in the `<head>` section as `<link href="http://file1.hpage.com/011708/49/html/boatstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> `, however, it isn't doing anything, to the page, do you know why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43005/discussion-between-john-smith-and-howard)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which color you're referring to by "default color", but [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables) shows the less values you can override in your stylesheet with the color you want to use.  So if you wanted to change the background color, you could add an entry in your less stylesheet for `@bodyBackground` that is set to `#BA935A`.

Comment: Alternatively if you download twitter bootstrap from their website, you can customize all of the colours you want to use, and then generate a custom build.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the answers, since I had an almost similar question. This is how I solved my problem (Based on the answers) to override default bootstrap properties.

```
<div class="well well-lg text-center" style="background-color:#EC031E; !important">
    This well has a Dark Red Background!
</div>
```

PS: I know its pretty late to answer this question, but I just hope this helps somebody wanting similar customization!

Answer (score -1):

Actually your question are not so clearly, but I'll share how to forcing our class on bootstrap class that I done.

If you want to change color, you can just change on the html **directly manually** like:

```
<div class="well" style="background-color:#88B5C2;">abc</div>
```

But if you want to use your own class. You can add `!important`. I give you an example how I forcing my style to my bootstrap class:

**css part**

```
.mystyle
{
  background-color:#88B5C2 !important;
}
```

**html part**

```
<div class="well mystyle">abc</div>
```

If you're not using `!important` the style still can be applied, but for more secure please using it, so your style would be prioritize than Boostrap's style.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to say. I understand how to change the background colour, that's not what I was getting at. All I want to do is change the colour of the main UI in the center of the page.

Comment: The one inside `div class="well"`? What I showed you was the way to forcing our style on Bootstrap style, on that example column foo will having style `text-align: right;`. Sorry for making confuse :(

Comment: I think so. I want to change the grey UI to the hex colour I specified in the question.

Comment: You should update your question with this information since as it currently reads it is not very helpful to anyone trying to answer your question

Comment: I updated my answer, please look for it. I done tried also. Hope can solve your problem

Comment: this isn't what he wanted to do, he wanted to change the default colour.